# Chart.js - How to hide gridlines outside the lines

Tags: chart.js

Chart.js

it's straight to show gridlines https://jsfiddle.net/haingdc/bgarmz7k/14/

```
gridLines: {
    lineWidth: 0,
}
```

So I need to display gridlines inside (or below) lines area like the below pic.

How can I hide gridlines outside?

[image]

Comment: I actually don't think that is possible. At least no easy way.

Comment: thanks @HeadhunterKev. Because grid lines are drawn first then to datasets. Im looking for a way to be able to draw grid lines after

Comment: @haind don't know if this may help you: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3957#issuecomment-404124071